# Configure IIS 7 to create a Windows event on HTTP error (or to trigger an action)

Tags: web-server, configuration, iis-7, windows-event-log

How to **configure IIS 7** so it **creates a Windows event** every time an **HTTP error occurs**?

The closest thing I found is this: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/iis/6.0-sdk/ms524984(v%3Dvs.90). It describes two configuration variables `AspErrorsToNTLog` and `AspLogErrorRequests`. However I cannot force IIS to create events for HTTP errors. And I am not even sure if these are applicable, as the documentation mentions only ASP errors and not HTTP errors.

> **AspErrorsToNTLog**
>
> When set to TRUE, this property specifies that **ASP errors** are logged to both the Event Viewer and to the IIS log file.
>
> When set to FALSE, this property specifies that **ASP errors** are logged only to the IIS log file.

The logging to file works properly. In `c:\inetpub\logs\LogFiles\...\u_ex200123.log`, we have the expected lines like this (notice the `500` near the end of the line)

```
2020-01-23 05:38:06 ip-address GET /MyService/ param1=value1&param2=value2|-|ASP_0146|New_Session_Failed 80 - ip-address - 500 0 0 545
```

To avoid the X-Y problem: We'd like to use it to trigger an action (such as sending an email to Operations) when some of the web services return HTTP status 500.

Comment: It is impractical to log every HTTP errors (if your definition is non-200 responses), as on a typical server there are countless ones https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/943891/the-http-status-code-in-iis-7-0-iis-7-5-and-iis-8-0 And that's also why the setting you found is ASP specific and only binds to 500 status code. Since most 500 responses are caused by unhandled exceptions in web apps, it should be the developers that implement reporting mechanisms inside, as that gives more context on what to report. Merely at IIS level you won't get much information to troubleshoot.

Comment: @LexLi I get your point and *generally* agree with you. However, we have a very specific small web service. It has quite low traffic but is crucial. We need the Operations to be immediatelly aware if a call fails, *before* the customer starts complaining. **Is there a way how to create a Windows event at least upon HTTP error 500?**

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with (free) 3rd party software. [EventSentry](https://www.eventsentry.com/features/log-file-monitoring) (Light) is one of the products that can do that by monitoring the actual log file and filtering on any text that occurs. There is nothing you have to do on the IIS side - for as long as it logs to the log file.

I actually found a screen cast that walks you through it: https://youtu.be/1Cu_e1PkI2w.

Comment: That's an interesting idea, I have not tought about it from this angle. We will give it a try if we do not find any solution *inside* IIS.